# Why is this code failing to process a diferent matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

This code is managing to get some matrix operations but when the initial values on the matrix is modified, the results are showed as NaN, I dont understand why because it is supposed to be able to manage (almost) any size of matrices.

```
%data matrix

   data=[0   1   0   1j
   0   2   0 0.8j
   1   2   0 0.4j
   1   3   0 0.2j
   2   3   0 0.2j
   3   4   0 0.08j];

 % from  to R   X
%Z=[0   1   0   1j
 %  0   2   0 0.8j
 %  1   2   0 0.4j
  % 1   3   0 0.2j
   %2   3   0 0.2j
   %3   4   0 0.08j];

%finding order of matrix in C language way
%o1=max(Z(:,1));
%o2=max(Z(:,2));
%order=(max(o1,o2))
%find number of rows of Z= Toatl number of nodes
%row=length(Z(:,1))

[row,col]=size(data);
order=col

%Change last column into admittance, now last column also inculdes R
for m=1:row
    data(m,4)=1/(data(m,3)+data(m,4));
end

Z2adm=data;

%Yadmittance as a matrixo of zeros first
Y=zeros(order,order);

%finding ybus matrix

%1-for off-digonal vlaues
for i=1:row
    for j=1:order
        %discard source node
        if data(i,1)==0||data(i,2)==0    
           a=0;
         %for off digonal entries
        elseif data(i,1)~=0||data(i,2)~=0
            Y(data(i,1),data(i,2))=-data(i,4);
            Y(data(i,2),data(i,1))=-data(i,4);
        end
        
    end
end
%2-digonal values 
for a=1:order     %for k
    for b=1:row
        if data(b,1)==a ||data(b,2)==a
           
            Y(a,a)=(Y(a,a)+data(b,4));
        end
    end
   
end
Ybus=Y

%To find Z bus
Zbus=inv(Y)

%As Ibus=Ybus*Vbus so we can find too if we know Ibus. As here two currnet
%sources so suppose
Ibus=[1;1;0;0];
Vbus=Ybus\Ibus
```

When the matrix original is used it works out without problem, but if you add or remove a line, this fails on `data`.

i.e. modyfing the data from the one showed to this
data=[0   1   0   1j
0   2   0 0.8j
1   2   0 0.4j
1   3   0 0.2j
2   3   0 0.2j];
%   3   4   0 0.08j

gives the next
[image]

Comment: Where exactly does it fail? What error(s) does it throw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the nested loops for `i` and `j`, you use the elements of the first two columns of `data` as indices. When you remove the last row from `data`, you remove the only row with an index `= 4`. As a result the fourth row and column of `Y` are unchanged, both remain at zero and `Y` is singular.

Comment: and how can adjust it to have the indice same as the number rows, this is supposed to calculate for any number of lines in data

Comment: @avelardo: The problem is setting `order` equal to the number of columns, which is always 4 regardless of how many nodes your circuit has.  In the code you tag as `finding order of matrix in C language way` you correctly set `order` to the largest node index.  Use the same approach in your MATLAB code.